# iOS Captive Network Assistant (CNA) does not load on some iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, captiveportal, captivenetwork

We are seeing an issue with iOS Captive Network Assistant (CNA). When a user selects public SSID to access internet, CNA does not load on some iPhones. This behavior is random and is **not** specific to any iPhone or iOS version. We checked on Captive Portal side; we are returning 200 OK with appropriate landing page content every time.

**Observations**:
We observed that iPhones typically send 4 requests to Captive Portal when opening CNA. When it fails to open CNA, we see 1 request only. Detail below.

**CNA launches**:

1. {name=Connection, value=close}, {name=User-Agent, value=CaptiveNetworkSupport-418 wispr}
2. {name=Connection, value=close}, {name=User-Agent, value=CaptiveNetworkSupport-418 wispr}
3. {name=Connection, value=close}, {name=User-Agent, value=CaptiveNetworkSupport-418 wispr}
4. {name=user-agent, value=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148}

Here, all requests with CaptiveNetworkSupport are on HTTP 1.0. While the user-agent shown on number 4 is on HTTP 2.0

**CNA does not launch**:

{name=Connection, value=close}, {name=User-Agent, value=CaptiveNetworkSupport-418 wispr}

We see 1 request only when CNA does not launch. In this case, the user-agent is either “CaptiveNetworkSupport” or “NetworkCTS”

Has anyone run into this kind of problem with iOS CNA?

**NOTE**: We do not have such problems on Android, Windows and MacOS. Also note that there is a known issue where CNA does not load sometimes when Captive Portal is not IPv6 enabled. In our case, we have IPv6 enabled.